# Can't install .net framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I'm having a weird problem where when I install the developer pack for the .NET framework, I can't choose to create a project with the .NET framework, I can only create .NET Core projects.

.NET website screenshot:

[image: .net website image]

That screenshot is the website that I've downloaded the developer pack from.

When I search for .NET framework projects:

[image: When I search .net framework]

As you can see from the second screenshot, whenever I search for .NET  framework, only .NET Core project choices show up.

Thank you for reading my post and I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: @user9938 OP wants the framework not .net core

Comment: You need something like this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

Comment: Open Visual Studio Installer, click Modify and ensure the appropriate Workloads are installed. Also click Individual Components and ensure both the SDK and Tsrgeting pack are installed for your desired .NET Framework version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to vs installer and modified your visual studio and install the remaining SDK and component.